# Exit Intent function is working, but no modal is popping up as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm putting an exit intent feature on my wordpress website and am having an unusual problem.

After loading in the script via wp_enqueue_script in functions.php, I then put the below function in my scripts file. It pulled in just fine.

After I access inspect element in chrome the console is indeed printing 'ouibounce fired'. However, nothing afterwards is working and no modals are popping up.

Also, just to eliminate another possibility,styles for the below ouibounce have been loaded into my styles file.

```js
var _ouibounce = ouibounce(document.getElementById('ouibounce-modal'), {
  aggressive: true,
  timer: 1,
  callback: function() {
    console.log('ouibounce fired!');
  }
});

body.on('click', function() {
  $('#ouibounce-modal').hide();
});

$('#ouibounce-modal .modal-footer').on('click', function() {
  $('#ouibounce-modal').hide();
});

$('#ouibounce-modal .modal').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();


});
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain himself? Really lost on this :\

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well I figured it out.

My filewatcher on my styles file was not compiling due to a sass-cache file. I restarted my editor and it worked just fine.